# CSS: Div straddling 2 other divs

Tags: css, overlay

I'm curious whether it's possible with CSS to have a `<div>` overlaying the `<div>` above and below, like so:

[image: The desired effect]

I've tried to use `margin-top: -40px;`, but that doesn't seem to work. I've tried `position:relative;` without any luck, either. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure!

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Y4FEA/1/)

The trick is managing the positioning of your `div`s, then setting the offset (top) correctly for the `div` you want overlapping.

```
<div></div>
<div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:relative; /* ensure the parent divs have a position set */
}
div:first-child {
    background:red;
}
div:last-child {
    background:blue;
}
div:last-child div {
    opacity:.5;
    height:50px;
    background:white;
    position:absolute; /* position relative to the parent */
    top:-25px; /* position the top to -25px (half its height) above the top of the parent */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## There are many ways to do this:

### With all `div`'s absolutely positioned

You can use `position: absolute` to achieve this. This is better if you are trying to build a web app as it sticks to the edges of the screen.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKG2R/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="top-section"></div>
<div id="banner-section"></div>
<div id="btm-section"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#top-section {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    background: red;
}

#btm-section {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
}

#banner-section {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    top: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

---

### With the `#banner-section` relatively positioned

You mentioned that you tried relative position. This is how you can achieve what you were trying to do. In this case, you want the `#banner-section` to be nested inside the `#btm-section`:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKG2R/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="top-section"></div>

<div id="btm-section">
   <div id="banner-section"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#banner-section {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

---

### With a negative margin on `#banner-section`

You also mentioned that you tried using a negative value for the `margin-top`. Here is a working example of that:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKG2R/2/)

#### HTML

(Also nested)

```
<div id="top-section"></div>

<div id="btm-section">
   <div id="banner-section"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#banner-section {
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

---

### You can also have it poking out of the top section

If the `#top-section` is static and the bottom section can extend past the bottom of the page, this might be the best option for you.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dKG2R/3/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="top-section">
    <div id="banner-section"></div>
</div>

<div id="btm-section"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
#banner-section {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50px;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 100px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Comment: This is great--thanks so much for the answer. I'm bummed it doesn't let me select two answers as correct!

Comment: No worries :) Just glad to help steer you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

Without further details you can do it as follows:

#### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/bD9WM/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="top-section"></div>
<div class="banner-section"></div>
<div class="btm-section"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-section{
    height:60px;
    background-color:red;
}
.btm-section{
    height:60px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.banner-section{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    margin-top:-20px;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

### End Result

The trick here is to have the middle div `banner-section` positioned absolutly, and with a margin-top value negative corresponding to half its height, giving us this end result:

[image: Screenshot]

## Explanation

Since the element with the CSS class `.banner-section` gets positioned absolutely, it will rise above in the document stack order. So the elements `.top-section` and `.btm-section` stay one after the other.

An element with `position:absolute` will then need some extra css to keep up with the desirable appearence, like a `width` declaration and a `height` declaration to set its size.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this one helps you

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJBCi.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="topSec"></div>
  <div class="midSec">Midcontent</div>
  <div class="btmSec"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
.topSec {
  height: 50%;
  background: red ;
}
.btmSec {
  height: 50%;
  background: yellow ;
}
.midSec {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 60px
}
```