# Properly place a button on two divs

Tags: html, css, button

Looking for the most efficient way to place a button that spans over two consequent divs

Like so:[image: btnoverdivs]

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566903/css-div-straddling-2-other-divs

Answer (score 2):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2gLL9x5x/

HTML

```
<div id="top">TOP</div>
<button>Button</button>
<div id="bottom">Bottom</div>
```

CSS

```
#top{
background-color:green;
width:500px;
height:200px;
}

#bottom{
background-color:red;
width:500px;
height:200px;
}

button{
position:absolute;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:220px;
```

}